# Negation of feminine nouns in the accusative case

Tags: отрицание

The rule given here is that the accusative case is used for animate/inanimate objects. If animate that means using the genitive case, if the sentence is positive, right?

Example:

> - (Masculine)  я вижу кота
> - (Feminine)  я вижу кошки

But what about the negative?

> - (Masculine)  я не вижу кота
> - (Feminine)  я не вижу кошку

It seems that feminine nouns of animate objects in the accusative do not change to the genitive, or as in inanimate objects you have a choice.  Is this true?

Comment: Sentence `я вижу кошки` is incorrect. Correct are `я вижу кошек` (plural) and `я вижу кошку` (singular). Which one did you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Well your assumption is slightly wrong. Correct feminine form of `я вижу кота` is `я вижу кошку`, so it it exactly like for negation `я не вижу кота`/`я не вижу кошку`.

Actually, it is the other way around, it's the form `я не вижу кошку` has an alternative form `я не вижу кошки`. So what you have notice is indeed something that exists.

As far as I know it's not that simple, it's not about feminine nouns, there are actually *some set* of rules when one should use accusative or genitive with some set of *verbs in negative*.

Here's a quote (and actually you can find [there](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr) a big, yet not full, set of rules I've mentioned):

> Трудность заключается в том, что в одних случаях тот или иной падеж
>   является предпочтительным, а в других существует равная возможность
>   употребления как родительного, так и винительного падежа.

So what you have noticed is exactly about some words that can be used in both cases. It's hard to me to provide a complete list of such words (or rules by which they are generated) but as of counter-example for your hypothesis: (non-feminine and non-animate) `я не нашёл здание` /`не нашёл здания`.

Some other counter-examples:

- Вчерашнего дня не воротишь / вчерашний день не воротишь.
- Не учуял запах газа / не учуял запаха газа.

Though indeed good point, I guess this should be investigated.
Here are even [more](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlv.html#sect201) rules about this.

Comment: я не нашёл [никакой] кошк**и** / я не нашел [конкретную] кошк**у**. Первый ответ будет на просьбу типа "Сходи в подвал, поймай какую-нибудь кошку на шапку", второй - "у нас Мypка убежала, попробуй её найти"

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely that rule works: if animate, it doesn't necessarily mean using the genitive (or vice versa). In your examples with the affirmative it's always accusative, while *both* cases are possible with negations.

> Я не вижу здесь никакого кота (никакой кошки) - нет здесь котов
>   (кошек)!

(strictly genitive)

> Я сейчас не вижу своего кота (свою кошку, fem.): его (её) заслоняет
>   монитор.

(preferably accusative)

> Я не вижу своего кота (своей кошки): куда-то убежал(а).

(preferably genitive)

As you can see, sometimes only context helps to tell genitive (кота) from accusative (кота). You only need to choose between cases with feminine in the examples above. I wouldn't dare to define any general rule, but with those examples, genitive tends to be used with objects which are considered *absent* (from the fact they are not seen).

As for animate/inanimate objects, there is a difference in accusative case endings for plural (which usually coincide with those in the nominative for inanimate objects), while both accusative/genitive are still possible in sentences with negation.

> Вы не кормите своих кошек?

(strictly accusative)

> Вы терпеть не можете кошек?

(more likely, genitive)

> Вы не будете есть огурцы?

(preferably accusative)

> Вы никогда не ели огурцов?

(preferably genitive)

Another tendency can be noticed from the latter group of examples: *genitive* is more likely to be used with '*abstractly*' mentioned objects, which are out of focus.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's not about animated/inanimated or feminine. It's just about ending of the word.
Totally doesn't matter if one is animated or inanimated if it ends with `a`, like `река`, or `палка`.
But definitely it's more common for Russian language that any word ending with `a` have feminine semantic. But not every word.
You can take for instance word `братишка` - which means little brother (masculine, animated) and it will *behave* exactly like word `кошка` - the correct examples already presented to you above: `братишки` `братишку` - both are correct.

Comment: it's not about endings, at least it's not only about nouns ending with 'а'

Comment: it may happen that I take the question wrong. but even now, I can't say what was the other meaning of the question. 
I believe the question was all about the rules of creating negation form of nouns, i.e. which ending in negative sentence to choose.

So basically, negative and positive doesn't differ, `вижу кота` vs `не вижу кота`; `вижу кошку` vs `не вижу кошку` AND the ending changes by cases (accusative, genitive) dictated indeed by the original ending `а/я` , see pictured tables: http://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/sushhestvitelnoe/tipyi-skloneniya-imen-sushhestvitelnyih.html

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's easier to illustrate these differences by examples from English. Actually it's much like this:

> Accusative: Я не вижу кошку --> I don't see (a / the) cat
>   Genitive: Я не вижу кошки --> I see no cat

So it's not about animate/inanimate nouns at all.